# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432 heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm not really sure why I'm getting this.  When I went to launch the app on Heroku i received a 404 error with message of not found and it's from my error handler in my app.js file, but I'm unsure what is going on.

Everything works locally??

```
server.js
/** Start server for jobly. */


const app = require('./app');
const { PORT } = require("./config");


app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log(`Server starting on port ${PORT}!`);
});

2020-07-17T03:49:35.103011+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2020-07-17T03:49:39.311369+00:00 app[web.1]: Using database jobly-db
2020-07-17T03:49:39.885564+00:00 app[web.1]: Server starting on port 6266!
2020-07-17T03:49:39.894114+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
2020-07-17T03:49:39.894116+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)
2020-07-17T03:49:39.894367+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
2020-07-17T03:49:39.894527+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
2020-07-17T03:49:40.080034+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-07-17T03:52:04.190766+00:00 app[api]: Attach DATABASE (@ref:postgresql-convex-54039) by user areacodelogic@gmail.com
```

Comment: Can you describe more regarding the Not Found error here?  Is it from a http request?

Comment: Yeah, it looks that way. ``` 2020-07-17T03:53:14.388981+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=damp-eyrie-25623.herokuapp.com request_id=207e7653-5b91-4586-ac84-91aeae9da8cc fwd="98.234.88.47" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=404 bytes=292 protocol=https ```.

Comment: And do you have a route handler for the `/` route?

Comment: Yeah, i have a route for /.

Answer (score 0):

please post your server.js code and Procfile.
Also by looking the error, it seems that you have used your localhost PostgreSQL host but you PostgreSQL on heroku, are you sure the addons is included in heroku ?
If it is added then on connection code, you need to use the that url to work. Example could be as below

```
    connectionString = 'postgresql://dbuser:secretpassword@database.server.com:3211/mydb'
```

Use like this:

```
    const { Pool, Client } = require('pg')
    const connectionString = 'postgresql://dbuser:secretpassword@database.server.com:3211/mydb'

    const pool = new Pool({
        connectionString: connectionString,
    })
```

or like this

```
    var client = new Client({
        user: "username",
        password: "pwd",
        database: "dbname",
        port: 5432,
        host: "host",
        ssl: true
    });
    client.connect(function () {
        console.log("connected");
    });
```

you could find the explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42429209/heroku-db-connection-refused)

Comment: I added the code to main question above.  What do you mean by addons?

Comment: where is the database connection part ?

Comment: '''
config.js

require("dotenv").config();

const SECRET_KEY = process.env.SECRET_KEY || 'test';

const PORT = +process.env.PORT || 3000;

let DB_URI;

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test'){
  DB_URI = 'jobly-test';
} else {
  DB_URI = process.env.DATABASE_URL || 'jobly-db'
}

module.exports = {
  SECRET_KEY,
  PORT,
  DB_URI,
};
____
db.js
const { Client } = require("pg");
const { DB_URI } = require("./config");

const client = new Client({
  connectionString: DB_URI
});

client.connect();


module.exports = client;

```

Comment: wha is the value of process.env.DATABASE_URL in your env

Comment: See, this process.env.NODE_ENV value will always be production in heroku unless you set it test yourself. Also do you have jobly-test database in heroku ? Heroku doesn't gives you databases on the fly. You have to add addons. you can find detail here --> https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql

Comment: I do have the database in heroku.  I added that.

Comment: If you have added that in your heroku, then it will have a connection url, use that. Have you set that URL in your heroku env\environment Variables?

Comment: Yeah, i believe i did that from the terminal.  Is there a way to confirm?

Comment: go to settings in your app and click on reveal config vars, verify env var name is exactly same in your code. Also if it is, try consoling the values in code and remove that test environment code for testing. And lets see what happens

Comment: So, I built out the front end and back end on two different Herokus, as advised.  My backend heroku has the DATABASE_URL with value, and the frontend heroku has the REACT_APP_BASE_URL.

Comment: I have updated the answer, please have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for helping out here.  That didn't work either.

Comment: which one did you try ? I am using the same code and i its working. try the later one instead. That shall work, and don't forget to replace the value with the actual credentials